# Repeated messages in chatView. how to clear view?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui, swiftui-list

- I have a chatView with a list of chatRow Views (messages)
- each chatView has a snapshot listener with firebase, so I should get real time updates if I add a new message to the conversation

The problem I have is: when I add a new message my chatView shows ALL the messages I added before plus the new message, PLUS the same list again....if I add another message then the list repeats again

I assume I need to drop/refresh the previous views shown in the Foreach loop...how can I drop/refresh the view so it can receive refreshed NON repeated data?

```
struct ChatView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var chatModel: ChatsViewModel
    
    let chat: Conversation
    let user = UserService.shared.user
    @State var messagesSnapshot = [Message]()
    
    @State var newMessageInput = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                ScrollViewReader { scrollView in
                    ScrollView {
                        
                        ForEach(chat.messages, id: \.id) { message in
                            if user.name == message.createdBy {
                                ChatRow(message: message, isMe: true)
                            } else {
                                ChatRow(message: message, isMe: false)
                            }
                        }
                        .onAppear(perform: {scrollView.scrollTo(chat.messages.count-1)})
                    }
                    
                }
                Spacer()
                
                //send a new message
                ZStack {
                    Rectangle()
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                    
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
                        .stroke(Color("LightGrayColor"), lineWidth: 2)
                        .padding()
                    
                    HStack {
                        TextField("New message...", text: $newMessageInput, onCommit: {
                            print("Send Message")
                        })
                        .padding(30)
                        
                        Button(action: {
                            chatModel.sendMessageChat(newMessageInput, in: chat, chatid: chat.id ?? "")
                            print("Send message.")
                        }) {
                            Image(systemName: "paperplane")
                                .imageScale(.large)
                                .padding(30)
                        }
                    }
                }
                .frame(height: 70)
            }
            .navigationTitle("Chat")
        }
        
    }
}
```

function to add message to the conversation

```
func addMessagesToConv(conversation: Conversation, index: Int) {
        var mensajesTotal = [Message]()
        
        let ref = self.db.collection("conversations").document(conversation.id!).collection("messages")
            .order(by: "date")
            .addSnapshotListener { querySnapshotmsg, error in
            
            if error == nil {
                //loop throug the messages/docs
                for msgDoc in querySnapshotmsg!.documents {
                    var m = Message() //emtpy struc message
                    m.createdBy = msgDoc["created_by"] as? String ?? ""
                    m.date = msgDoc["date"] as? Timestamp ?? Timestamp()
                    m.msg = msgDoc["msg"] as? String ?? ""
                    m.id = msgDoc.documentID //firebase auto id
                    
                    mensajesTotal.append(m) //append this message to the total of messages
                    self.chats[index].messages.removeAll()
                    self.chats[index].messages = mensajesTotal
                }
            } else {
                print("error: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: you could try putting these 2 lines: `self.chats[index].messages.removeAll()` 
and `self.chats[index].messages = mensajesTotal` 
outside the `for msgDoc in querySnapshotmsg!.documents {...} `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've defined `mensajesTotal` *outside* of your snapshot listener. So, it's getting appended to every time.

To fix this, move this line:

```
var mensajesTotal = [Message]()
```

to inside the `addSnapshotListener` closure.

Comment: ay ay ay, I should have seen that, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

1. Clear `mensajesTotal` each time you get an update from the database, as @jnpdx's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69548189) shows.
2. Process the more granular updates in [`querySnapshotmsg.documentChanges`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasefirestore/api/reference/Classes/QuerySnapshot#documentchanges) to perform increment updates in your UI, as also shown in the documentation on [detecting changes between snapshots](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#view_changes_between_snapshots).

There is no difference in the data transferred between client and server between these approaches, so use whatever is easiest (that'd typically be #1) or most efficient on the UI (that's usually #2).

Comment: thanks I'll read about option 2, thanks!